# DataExplorer collecting data on daily # questions: Problems with grouping over the union

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am trying to collect a wide range of information:

1. the daily # of questions posted from users with a certain reputation
2. the vote types on these questions from these users
3. how the questions were marked

Because I am trying to collect data on a handful of variables I am trying to do this with a single code under a union. While the *individual codes without the union run fine*, when I try combine them into one code using a union (because it saves time downloading the multiple excel files from Data Explorer) I get the following error message:

```
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'total'.
The multi-part identifier "p.CreationDate" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "p.CreationDate" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "p.CreationDate" could not be bound.
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
--grouping over the union
SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)),
sum(questions) as [questions],
sum(votes) as [votes],
sum(marks) as [marks]
from
(
-- questions from users with a certain reputation
  SELECT
  DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)),
  count(*) as [questions],
  0  as [votes],
  0 as [marks]
  from Posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
and  DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))> '2015-07-31 00:00:00'
and u.reputation=1
GROUP BY
DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
union
-- up votes on questions from users with certain reputation
SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)),
0 as [questions],
count(*)  as [votes],
0 as [marks]
from Posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
inner join votes v
 on v.postid = p.id
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
and  DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))> '2015-07-31 00:00:00'
and v.votetypeid=2
and u.reputation=1
GROUP BY
DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
union
-- questions marked as duplicates from users with certain reputation
SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)),
0 as [questions],
0 as [votes],
count(*) as [marks]
from Posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
inner join PostHistory ph on ph.postid = p.id 
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
and  DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))> '2015-07-31 00:00:00'
and ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 10 -- closed
and ph.comment = 101 -- as duplicate (adjust as needed 102 = offtopic)
and u.reputation=1
GROUP BY
DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
) as total
GROUP BY
DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error description is very clear.

1. You missed to set alias name for the first column in the sub query.  After `DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))` add  `AS CreationDate` it will solve the first error.
2. In the outer query the `p.CreationDate` can not be access it have scope with in the sub-query only. In outer query you need to call simply `CreationDate` or `total.CreationDate`. *(total is the alias name in your case)* and the same in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. so those 3 `multi-part identifier` errors will solve.

Please find the working code of yours: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/492698/collecting-data-on-daily-question

```
--grouping over the UNION
SELECT  Total.CreationDate,
        SUM(Total.questions) AS [questions],
        SUM(Total.votes) AS [votes],
        SUM(Total.marks) AS [marks]
FROM
(
    -- questions FROM  users with a certain reputation
    SELECT
    DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)) AS CreationDate,
    COUNT(*) AS [questions],
    0 AS [votes],
    0 AS [marks]
    FROM  Posts p
    INNER JOIN users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
    WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
        AND DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)) > '2015-07-31 00:00:00'
        AND u.reputation = 1
    GROUP BY DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
    
    UNION
    
    -- up votes on questions FROM  users with certain reputation
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)) AS CreationDate,
    0 AS [questions],
    COUNT(*) AS [votes],
    0 AS [marks]
    FROM  Posts p
    INNER JOIN users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
    INNER JOIN votes v on v.postid = p.id
    WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
        AND DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)) > '2015-07-31 00:00:00'
        AND v.votetypeid = 2
        AND u.reputation = 1
    GROUP BY DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
    
    UNION
    
    -- questions marked AS duplicates FROM  users with certain reputation
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)) AS CreationDate,
    0 AS [questions],
    0 AS [votes],
    COUNT(*) AS [marks]
    FROM  Posts p
    INNER JOIN users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
    INNER JOIN PostHistory ph on ph.postid = p.id 
    WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
        AND  DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate)) > '2015-07-31 00:00:00'
        AND ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 10 -- closed
        AND ph.comment = 101 -- AS duplicate (adjust AS needed 102 = offtopic)
        AND u.reputation = 1
    GROUP BY DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, p.CreationDate))
) AS Total
GROUP BY Total.CreationDate
ORDER BY Total.CreationDate
```